# Host your own minecraft question

Tags: discussion

Is it okay to ask how to host a minecraft server using linux or windows and having the community come up with a massive HOWTO?

I have begun one using a specific architecture (webmin and Ubuntu Linux) for another question but I feel that helping individuals get one started on a Vanilla linux or Vanilla windows server may benefit us greatly.

Comment: I'd write it as a blog post if it'd be a massive how-to

Comment: Or even, as a question with an answer linking to said blog post . . .

Comment: http://blog.gaming.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @3ventic holy crap I didnt even know we had that.

Comment: Last blog was posted before I joined so it doesn't seem like it's too active.

Comment: @3ventic Well Maybe getting something informative on it may be useful for traffic then.

Comment: I'd at least post a summary of the method as part of the answer, and not just link it to a blog post, if you're going to do something like that.

Answer (score 2):

If your Q&A is on-topic, it is perfectly fine. Words from Jeff Atwood one of the founders of Stack Exchange.

[It’s OK to Ask and Answer Your Own Questions](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/)

> To be crystal clear, **it is not merely OK to ask and answer your own question, it is explicitly encouraged.**

and

> Bottom line — **never hesitate to ask and answer your own question on any Stack Exchange site**. Please do! It’s all part of our shared mission to make the internet better.

Comment: Do note that when posting your own question and answer together, each one absolutely **needs** to stand on its own; the question must be something that would be acceptable without your answer, and the answer must be a valid answer to the question asked.